# Add text flush left below plot in python

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to add text beneath a plot, which includes the source of the used data.
It should be positioned at the edge of the image, so beneath the longest ytick and if possible at a fixed vertical distance to the x-axis.

**My approach:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

country = ['Portugal','Spain','Austria','Italy','France','Federal Republic of Germany']
value = [6,8,10,12,14,25]

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.barh(country,value)
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.text(-18,-2.5,'Source: blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla',ha='left')
```

[Plot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OObqp.png)

I used `plt.text()`. My problem with the command is, that I have to manually try x and y values (in the code: -18,-2.5) for different plots.
Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I got the box info of yticklabels, and then got the leftmost x location for all the yticklabels. Finally, the blended transform method was used to add text with some location adjustments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

country = ['Portugal','Spain','Austria','Italy','France','Federal Republic of Germany']
value = [6,8,10,12,14,25]

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.barh(country,value)
plt.xlabel('x-axis')

ax = plt.gca()
fig =plt.gcf()

fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()
labs = ax.get_yticklabels()
xlocs = []
for ilab in labs:
    xlocs.append(ilab.get_window_extent().x0)

print(xlocs)
x0 = min(xlocs)
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(IdentityTransform(), ax.transAxes)
plt.text(x0-2.5,-0.2,'Source: blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla',ha='left',transform=trans)
plt.savefig("flush.png",bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]